# How to remove hover state from the parent of a clicked element on mobile?

Tags: javascript, css, mobile, hover

I have a tooltip that appears when a toggle is hovered over.

On mobile a click on a toggle opens it, and another click anywhere outside of it closes it.

I want to make it so a click inside the popup (or anywhere, really) will also remove the hover state (and close the popup).

Let's say it looks like this and the popup, when visible, hides the hover:

```css
.popup {
  border: 3px solid green;
  background-color: yellow;
  display: none;
  height: 100vw;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
  top: -1em;
  width: 100vw;
}

.container:hover .popup {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="text">
    TEXT
  </div>

  <div class="popup">
    popup content
  </div>
</div>
```

So now in, mobile, there's no easy way to deactivate the hover. Is there a way to trigger an end to the hover state of `.container` with a click on `.popup` (or anywhere really)? Apologies if this has already been asked. I'd prefer to use CSS & vanilla JavasScript and all of the solutions I can see use jQuery.

Comment: It could be hidden when it gets focus via a tap (needs a `tabindex` set on the popup element)  - but then that focus state would persist, until the user taps somewhere else. But since "hovering" _again_ would actually mean the user has to _tap_ the container again on mobile, that should remove the focus from the popup again ... Can't properly test this on a mobile right now, but I suppose it could work.

Comment: _"I'd prefer to use CSS & vanilla JavasScript and all of the solutions I can see use jQuery."_ - rewriting a jQuery solution to vanilla JS should probably not be rocket science in a case like this though ...